# Append to the description of OpenAPI 3.0 file using jq

Tags: jq, openapi

So I have the following OpenAPI 3.0 file (this is NOT a full file, just grab the full one from the open api pet store sample demo):

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "//petstore.swagger.io/v2",
      "description": "Default server"
    },
    {
      "url": "//petstore.swagger.io/sandbox",
      "description": "Sandbox server"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Swagger Petstore",
    "termsOfService": "http://swagger.io/terms/",
    "contact": {
      "name": "API Support",
      "email": "apiteam@swagger.io",
      "url": "https://github.com/Redocly/redoc"
    },
    "x-logo": {
      "url": "https://redocly.github.io/redoc/petstore-logo.png",
      "altText": "Petstore logo"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
    }
  },
  "externalDocs": {
    "description": "Find out how to create Github repo for your OpenAPI spec.",
    "url": "https://github.com/Rebilly/generator-openapi-repo"
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "pet",
      "description": "Everything about your Pets"
    },
    {
      "name": "store",
      "description": "Access to Petstore orders"
    },
    {
      "name": "user",
      "description": "Operations about user"
    },
    {
      "name": "pet_model",
      "x-displayName": "The Pet Model",
      "description": "<SchemaDefinition schemaRef=\"#/components/schemas/Pet\" />\n"
    },
    {
      "name": "store_model",
      "x-displayName": "The Order Model",
      "description": "<SchemaDefinition schemaRef=\"#/components/schemas/Order\" exampleRef=\"#/components/examples/Order\" showReadOnly={true} showWriteOnly={true} />\n"
    }
  ],
  "x-tagGroups": [
    {
      "name": "General",
      "tags": [
        "pet",
        "store"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "User Management",
      "tags": [
        "user"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Models",
      "tags": [
        "pet_model",
        "store_model"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/pet": {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "Accept-Language",
          "in": "header",
          "description": "The language you prefer for messages. Supported values are en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-US",
          "example": "en-US",
          "required": false,
          "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "en-AU"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "cookieParam",
          "in": "cookie",
          "description": "Some cookie",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          }
        }
      ],
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Add a new pet to the store",
        "description": "Add new pet to the store inventory.",
        "operationId": "addPet",
        "responses": {
          "405": {
            "description": "Invalid input"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "petstore_auth": [
              "write:pets",
              "read:pets"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "x-codeSamples": [
          {
            "lang": "C#",
            "source": "PetStore.v1.Pet pet = new PetStore.v1.Pet();\npet.setApiKey(\"your api key\");\npet.petType = PetStore.v1.Pet.TYPE_DOG;\npet.name = \"Rex\";\n// set other fields\nPetStoreResponse response = pet.create();\nif (response.statusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)\n{\n  // Successfully created\n}\nelse\n{\n  // Something wrong -- check response for errors\n  Console.WriteLine(response.getRawResponse());\n}\n"
          },
          {
            "lang": "PHP",
            "source": "$form = new \\PetStore\\Entities\\Pet();\n$form->setPetType(\"Dog\");\n$form->setName(\"Rex\");\n// set other fields\ntry {\n    $pet = $client->pets()->create($form);\n} catch (UnprocessableEntityException $e) {\n    var_dump($e->getErrors());\n}\n"
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "$ref": "#/components/requestBodies/Pet"
        }
      },
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Update an existing pet",
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "updatePet",
        "responses": {
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid ID supplied"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Pet not found"
          },
          "405": {
            "description": "Validation exception"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "petstore_auth": [
              "write:pets",
              "read:pets"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "x-codeSamples": [
          {
            "lang": "PHP",
            "source": "$form = new \\PetStore\\Entities\\Pet();\n$form->setPetId(1);\n$form->setPetType(\"Dog\");\n$form->setName(\"Rex\");\n// set other fields\ntry {\n    $pet = $client->pets()->update($form);\n} catch (UnprocessableEntityException $e) {\n    var_dump($e->getErrors());\n}\n"
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "$ref": "#/components/requestBodies/Pet"
        }
      }
    },
    "/pet/{petId}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Find pet by ID",
        "description": "Returns a single pet",
        "operationId": "getPetById",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "petId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ID of pet to return",
            "required": true,
            "deprecated": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int64"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                }
              },
              "application/xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid ID supplied"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Pet not found"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "api_key": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Updates a pet in the store with form data",
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "updatePetWithForm",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "petId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ID of pet that needs to be updated",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int64"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "405": {
            "description": "Invalid input"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "petstore_auth": [
              "write:pets",
              "read:pets"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "name": {
                    "description": "Updated name of the pet",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "status": {
                    "description": "Updated status of the pet",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Deletes a pet",
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "deletePet",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "api_key",
            "in": "header",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "example": "Bearer <TOKEN>"
          },
          {
            "name": "petId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Pet id to delete",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int64"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid pet value"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "petstore_auth": [
              "write:pets",
              "read:pets"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/pet/{petId}/uploadImage": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "uploads an image",
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "uploadFile",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "petId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ID of pet to update",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int64"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ApiResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "petstore_auth": [
              "write:pets",
              "read:pets"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/octet-stream": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "binary"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/pet/findByStatus": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Finds Pets by status",
        "description": "Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings",
        "operationId": "findPetsByStatus",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "status",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Status values that need to be considered for filter",
            "required": true,
            "style": "form",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "minItems": 1,
              "maxItems": 3,
              "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "available",
                  "pending",
                  "sold"
                ],
                "default": "available"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                  }
                }
              },
              "application/xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid status value"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "petstore_auth": [
              "write:pets",
              "read:pets"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/pet/findByTags": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Finds Pets by tags",
        "description": "Multiple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.",
        "operationId": "findPetsByTags",
        "deprecated": true,
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "tags",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Tags to filter by",
            "required": true,
            "style": "form",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                  }
                }
              },
              "application/xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "maxItems": 999,
                  "items": {
                    "maxItems": 111,
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid tag value"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "petstore_auth": [
              "write:pets",
              "read:pets"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/store/inventory": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "store"
        ],
        "summary": "Returns pet inventories by status",
        "description": "Returns a map of status codes to quantities",
        "operationId": "getInventory",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "minProperties": 2,
                  "additionalProperties": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "api_key": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/store/order": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "store"
        ],
        "summary": "Place an order for a pet",
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "placeOrder",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Order"
                }
              },
              "application/xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Order"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid Order",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "example": {
                  "status": 400,
                  "message": "Invalid Order"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Order"
              }
            }
          },
          "description": "order placed for purchasing the pet",
          "required": true
        }
      }
    },
    "/store/order/{orderId}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "store"
        ],
        "summary": "Find purchase order by ID",
        "description": "For valid response try integer IDs with value <= 5 or > 10. Other values will generated exceptions",
        "operationId": "getOrderById",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "orderId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ID of pet that needs to be fetched",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int64",
              "minimum": 1,
              "maximum": 5
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Order"
                }
              },
              "application/xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Order"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid ID supplied"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Order not found"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "store"
        ],
        "summary": "Delete purchase order by ID",
        "description": "For valid response try integer IDs with value < 1000. Anything above 1000 or nonintegers will generate API errors",
        "operationId": "deleteOrder",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "orderId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ID of the order that needs to be deleted",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "minimum": 1
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid ID supplied"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Order not found"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/store/subscribe": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "store"
        ],
        "summary": "Subscribe to the Store events",
        "description": "Add subscription for a store events",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "callbackUrl": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "uri",
                    "description": "This URL will be called by the server when the desired event will occur",
                    "example": "https://myserver.com/send/callback/here"
                  },
                  "eventName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Event name for the subscription",
                    "enum": [
                      "orderInProgress",
                      "orderShipped",
                      "orderDelivered"
                    ],
                    "example": "orderInProgress"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "callbackUrl",
                  "eventName"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "Subscription added",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "subscriptionId": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "example": "AAA-123-BBB-456"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "callbacks": {
          "orderInProgress": {
            "{$request.body#/callbackUrl}?event={$request.body#/eventName}": {
              "servers": [
                {
                  "url": "//callback-url.path-level/v1",
                  "description": "Path level server 1"
                },
                {
                  "url": "//callback-url.path-level/v2",
                  "description": "Path level server 2"
                }
              ],
              "post": {
                "summary": "Order in Progress (Summary)",
                "description": "A callback triggered every time an Order is updated status to \"inProgress\" (Description)",
                "externalDocs": {
                  "description": "Find out more",
                  "url": "https://more-details.com/demo"
                },
                "requestBody": {
                  "content": {
                    "application/json": {
                      "schema": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "orderId": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "example": "123"
                          },
                          "timestamp": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "date-time",
                            "example": "2018-10-19T16:46:45Z"
                          },
                          "status": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "example": "inProgress"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "application/xml": {
                      "schema": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "orderId": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "example": "123"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "example": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<root>\n  <orderId>123</orderId>\n  <status>inProgress</status>\n  <timestamp>2018-10-19T16:46:45Z</timestamp>\n</root>\n"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "responses": {
                  "200": {
                    "description": "Callback successfully processed and no retries will be performed",
                    "content": {
                      "application/json": {
                        "schema": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "someProp": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "example": "123"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "299": {
                    "description": "Response for cancelling subscription"
                  },
                  "500": {
                    "description": "Callback processing failed and retries will be performed"
                  }
                },
                "x-codeSamples": [
                  {
                    "lang": "C#",
                    "source": "PetStore.v1.Pet pet = new PetStore.v1.Pet();\npet.setApiKey(\"your api key\");\npet.petType = PetStore.v1.Pet.TYPE_DOG;\npet.name = \"Rex\";\n// set other fields\nPetStoreResponse response = pet.create();\nif (response.statusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)\n{\n  // Successfully created\n}\nelse\n{\n  // Something wrong -- check response for errors\n  Console.WriteLine(response.getRawResponse());\n}\n"
                  },
                  {
                    "lang": "PHP",
                    "source": "$form = new \\PetStore\\Entities\\Pet();\n$form->setPetType(\"Dog\");\n$form->setName(\"Rex\");\n// set other fields\ntry {\n    $pet = $client->pets()->create($form);\n} catch (UnprocessableEntityException $e) {\n    var_dump($e->getErrors());\n}\n"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "put": {
                "description": "Order in Progress (Only Description)",
                "servers": [
                  {
                    "url": "//callback-url.operation-level/v1",
                    "description": "Operation level server 1 (Operation override)"
                  },
                  {
                    "url": "//callback-url.operation-level/v2",
                    "description": "Operation level server 2 (Operation override)"
                  }
                ],
                "requestBody": {
                  "content": {
                    "application/json": {
                      "schema": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "orderId": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "example": "123"
                          },
                          "timestamp": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "date-time",
                            "example": "2018-10-19T16:46:45Z"
                          },
                          "status": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "example": "inProgress"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "application/xml": {
                      "schema": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "orderId": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "example": "123"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "example": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<root>\n  <orderId>123</orderId>\n  <status>inProgress</status>\n  <timestamp>2018-10-19T16:46:45Z</timestamp>\n</root>\n"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "responses": {
                  "200": {
                    "description": "Callback successfully processed and no retries will be performed",
                    "content": {
                      "application/json": {
                        "schema": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "someProp": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "example": "123"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
    }
  }
}
```

What needs to be done is that the operationId of each endpoint needs to be appended to each description. But please don't just do .description + operationId, because I am trying to do something more complex. What eventually will happen is that there is another json file where keys are operationIds. So in the current file, I will need to append content to the descriptions from that third file based on operationId. Something like this:

```
| .["endpoint_descriptions"] as $endpoint_descriptions
| .paths[][] as $paths | .description |= . + $endpoint_descriptions[$endpoint_descriptions].description
```

So, please account for that when offering a solution. Thanks.

I tried

```
| .["endpoint_descriptions"] as $endpoint_descriptions
| .paths[][] as $paths | .description |= . + $endpoint_descriptions[$endpoint_descriptions].description
```

Comment: Read in that "other file" using `--argfile` or `--slurpfile`, turn that content into a lookup table using `INDEX`, and bind it to a variable. Then, traverse your regular input, e.g. using `.paths[][]` and set `.description` based on that context's `.description` and/or `.operationId` with using the lookup table from the variable.

Comment: Please show the content of the "other JSON file"